# Optimize mysql table indexes

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the following situation and want to choose the optimum indexes ( some singles indexes and some multiple indexes).

**Row Number : 14,000,000**

**Table : Add**

```
 CREATE TABLE `Add` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Description` longtext,
  `IDUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DateAdded` datetime(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDCategory` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RowVersion` datetime NOT NULL,
  `IDStatus` int(11) DEFAULT '3',
  `IDModeration` int(11) DEFAULT '4',
  `Price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateFrom` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateTo` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDRegion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDCity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDNeighbourhood` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateAccepted` datetime(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateUpdated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShowLandLine` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateUpToDated` datetime(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Telephone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserType` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Neighbourhood` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IP` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FullEditToken` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDSource` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ExpiredAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `BadWordsFlag` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `IX_Add_DateFrom` (`DateFrom`),
  KEY `IX_Add_IDUser` (`IDUser`),
  KEY `IX_Add_DateUpdated` (`DateUpdated`),
  KEY `IX_Add_DateUpToDated` (`DateUpToDated`),
  KEY `IX_Add_DateTo` (`DateTo`),
  KEY `IX_Add_ON_IDUser_IDStatus_IDModeratiON_DateFrom_DateTo` (`IDUser`,`IDStatus`,`IDModeration`,`DateFrom`,`DateTo`),
  KEY `IX_Add_DateAdded` (`DateAdded`),
  KEY `IX_Add_Telephone` (`Telephone`),
  KEY `FK_Add_AddModeration` (`IDModeration`),
  KEY `FK_Add_AddStatus` (`IDStatus`),
  KEY `FK_Add_Category` (`IDCategory`),
  KEY `FK_Add_col_city` (`IDCity`),
  KEY `FK_Add_col_neighbourhood` (`IDNeighbourhood`),
  KEY `FK_Add_col_region` (`IDRegion`),
  KEY `IDSource` (`IDSource`),
  KEY `IX_Add_Name` (`Name`),
  KEY `IX_Add_IP` (`IP`),
  KEY `IX_Add_UserType` (`UserType`),
  KEY `IX_Add_IDUser_IDStatus` (`IDUser`,`IDStatus`),
  KEY `FullEditToken` (`FullEditToken`),
  KEY `IX_ExpiredAt` (`ExpiredAt`),
  CONSTRAINT `Add_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`IDSource`) REFERENCES `AddSource` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Add_AddModeration` FOREIGN KEY (`IDModeration`) REFERENCES `AddModeration` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Add_AddStatus` FOREIGN KEY (`IDStatus`) REFERENCES `AddStatus` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Add_Category` FOREIGN KEY (`IDCategory`) REFERENCES `Category` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Add_User` FOREIGN KEY (`IDUser`) REFERENCES `User` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Add_col_city` FOREIGN KEY (`IDCity`) REFERENCES `col_city` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Add_col_neighbourhood` FOREIGN KEY (`IDNeighbourhood`) REFERENCES `col_neighbourhood` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Add_col_region` FOREIGN KEY (`IDRegion`) REFERENCES `col_region` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16452993 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

`show index from Add` return :

```
+-------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                                               | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Add   |          0 | PRIMARY                                                |            1 | ID              | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_DateFrom                                        |            1 | DateFrom        | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_IDUser                                          |            1 | IDUser          | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_DateUpdated                                     |            1 | DateUpdated     | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_DateUpToDated                                   |            1 | DateUpToDated   | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_DateTo                                          |            1 | DateTo          | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_ON_IDUser_IDStatus_IDModeratiON_DateFrom_DateTo |            1 | IDUser          | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_ON_IDUser_IDStatus_IDModeratiON_DateFrom_DateTo |            2 | IDStatus        | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_ON_IDUser_IDStatus_IDModeratiON_DateFrom_DateTo |            3 | IDModeration    | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_ON_IDUser_IDStatus_IDModeratiON_DateFrom_DateTo |            4 | DateFrom        | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_ON_IDUser_IDStatus_IDModeratiON_DateFrom_DateTo |            5 | DateTo          | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_DateAdded                                       |            1 | DateAdded       | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_Telephone                                       |            1 | Telephone       | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | FK_Add_AddModeration                                   |            1 | IDModeration    | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | FK_Add_AddStatus                                       |            1 | IDStatus        | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | FK_Add_Category                                        |            1 | IDCategory      | A         |         190 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | FK_Add_col_city                                        |            1 | IDCity          | A         |         635 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | FK_Add_col_neighbourhood                               |            1 | IDNeighbourhood | A         |         952 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | FK_Add_col_region                                      |            1 | IDRegion        | A         |          63 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IDSource                                               |            1 | IDSource        | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_Name                                            |            1 | Name            | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_IP                                              |            1 | IP              | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_UserType                                        |            1 | UserType        | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_IDUser_IDStatus                                 |            1 | IDUser          | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_Add_IDUser_IDStatus                                 |            2 | IDStatus        | A         |        1905 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | FullEditToken                                          |            1 | FullEditToken   | A         |         127 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Add   |          1 | IX_ExpiredAt                                           |            1 | ExpiredAt       | A         |         100 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
27 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and our major queries are

## most queries used in system

Common part:

```
SELECT  `a`.`Description` AS `Description`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('=', `catt`.`Name`,
                             IF(`gc`.`Name` IS NOT NULL,
                                `gc`.`Name`, `aav`.`Value`))) AS `Attributes`,
        (( SELECT  IF(`ae`.`IDAdmin` IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('Admin=', `adm`.`adminName`),
                       IF(`ae`.`IDUser` IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('USER=', `ae`.`IDUser`), '') )
                FROM  `AddEvent` AS `ae`
                LEFT JOIN  `Admin` AS `adm`  ON `ae`.`IDAdmin` = `adm`.`adminId`
                WHERE  `a`.`ID` = `ae`.`IDAdd`
                ORDER BY  `ae`.`AddedAt` DESC
                LIMIT  1)
         ) AS `AdminOrUser`,
        'accepted' AS `AddStatus`,
        `a`.`ID` AS `ID`,
        `a`.`Name` AS `Name`, `a`.`IDStatus` AS `IDStatus`, `a`.`BadWordsFlag` AS `BadWordsFlag`,
        `a`.`Price` AS `Price`, `u`.`TelephonePrimary` AS `Telephone`,
        `a`.`DateTo` AS `DateTo`,
        IF(`a`.`DateTo`, `a`.`DateTo`, `a`.`DateAdded`) AS `CustomDate`,
        `a`.`IDModeration` AS `IDModeration`,
        ( ( SELECT  1
                FROM  `AddChanges` AS `ac`
                WHERE  `ac`.`IDAdd` = `a`.`ID`
                  AND  `ac`.`IDModeration` = 4
                ORDER BY  `ac`.`ID` DESC
                LIMIT  1) ) AS `HasChange`,
        ( ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('>', `ai`.`Path`, `ai`.`IsDefault`))
                    FROM  `AddImage` AS `ai`
                    WHERE  `ai`.`IDAdd` = `a`.`ID`) ) AS `Images`,
        `ca2`.`Name` AS `ParentCategory`,
        `ca1`.`Name` AS `Category`,
        `r`.`Name` AS `RegionName`,
        `ct`.`Name` AS `CityName`,
        `n`.`Name` AS `NeighbourhoodName`,
        `u`.`Email` AS `Email`
    FROM  `Add` AS `a`
    LEFT JOIN  `User` AS `u`         ON `u`.`ID` = `a`.`IDUser`
    LEFT JOIN  `Category` AS `ca1`   ON `ca1`.`ID` = `a`.`IDCategory`
    LEFT JOIN  `Category` AS `ca2`   ON `ca2`.`ID` = `ca1`.`IDParent`
    LEFT JOIN  `col_region` AS `r`   ON `r`.`Id` = `a`.`IDRegion`
    LEFT JOIN  `col_city` AS `ct`    ON `ct`.`Id` = `a`.`IDCity`
    LEFT JOIN  `col_neighbourhood` AS `n`     ON `n`.`Id` = `a`.`IDNeighbourhood`
    LEFT JOIN  `AddAttributeValues` AS `aav`  ON `aav`.`IDAdd` = `a`.`ID`
    LEFT JOIN  `CategoryAttribute` AS `catt`  ON `catt`.`ID` = `aav`.`IDCategoryAttribute`
    LEFT JOIN  `GenericCollection` AS `gc`    ON `gc`.`ID` = `aav`.`Value`
```

#1 detailed view

```
    WHERE (`a`.`DateTo` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
      AND  `a`.`IDStatus` = 1
      AND  `a`.`IDModeration` = 1 )
      AND (`a`.`IDStatus` <> 2)
    GROUP BY  `a`.`ID`
    ORDER BY  `a`.`ID` DESC
    LIMIT  51
```

# detailed with state

```
    WHERE  ((`a`.`DateTo` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
                      AND  `a`.`IDStatus` = 1
                      AND  `a`.`IDModeration` = 1
            )
              AND  (`a`.`IDStatus` <> 2)
           )
      AND  (`a`.`IDRegion` = '8')
    GROUP BY  `a`.`ID`
    ORDER BY  `a`.`ID` DESC
    LIMIT  51
```

# detailed with category

```
    WHERE  ((`a`.`DateTo` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
                      AND  `a`.`IDStatus` = 1
                      AND  `a`.`IDModeration` = 1
            )
              AND  (`a`.`IDStatus` <> 2)
           )
      AND  (`a`.`IDCategory` = '43627'
              OR  `ca1`.`IDParent` = '43627'
              OR  `ca1`.`IDParent` IN (
                SELECT  `ca3`.`ID` AS `ID`
                    FROM  `Category` AS `ca3`
                    WHERE  `ca3`.`IDParent` = '43627')
           )
    GROUP BY  `a`.`ID`
    ORDER BY  `a`.`ID` DESC
    LIMIT  51
```

#detailed with date category state

```
    WHERE  (((((`a`.`DateTo` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
                                              AND  `a`.`IDStatus` = 1
                                              AND  `a`.`IDModeration` = 1)
                                      AND  (`a`.`IDStatus` <> 2)
                          )
                              AND  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`a`.`DateAdded`) >= '1503430200'))
                      AND  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`a`.`DateAdded`) <= '1505071799')
            )
              AND  (`a`.`IDCategory` = '43627'
                      OR  `ca1`.`IDParent` = '43627'
                      OR  `ca1`.`IDParent` IN (
                        SELECT  `ca3`.`ID` AS `ID`
                            FROM  `Category` AS `ca3`
                            WHERE  `ca3`.`IDParent` = '43627'))
           )
      AND  (`a`.`IDRegion` = '8')
    GROUP BY  `a`.`ID`
    ORDER BY  `a`.`ID` DESC
    LIMIT  51
```

# summary mode

```
SELECT  'accepted' AS `AddStatus`, `a`.`ID` AS `ID`, `a`.`Name` AS `Name`,
        `a`.`IDStatus` AS `IDStatus`, `a`.`BadWordsFlag` AS `BadWordsFlag`,
        `a`.`Price` AS `Price`, `u`.`TelephonePrimary` AS `Telephone`,
`a`.`DateTo` AS `DateTo`,
IF(`a`.`DateTo`, `a`.`DateTo`, `a`.`DateAdded`) AS `CustomDate`,
`a`.`IDModeration` AS `IDModeration`,
    ( ( SELECT  1
            FROM  `AddChanges` AS `ac`
            WHERE  `ac`.`IDAdd` = `a`.`ID`
              AND  `ac`.`IDModeration` = 4
            ORDER BY  `ac`.`ID` DESC
            LIMIT  1)) AS `HasChange`,
    ( ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('>', `ai`.`Path`, `ai`.`IsDefault`))
            FROM  `AddImage` AS `ai`
            WHERE  `ai`.`IDAdd` = `a`.`ID`)
    ) AS `Images`, `ca2`.`Name` AS `ParentCategory`,
        `ca1`.`Name` AS `Category`, `r`.`Name` AS `RegionName`,
        `ct`.`Name` AS `CityName`, `n`.`Name` AS `NeighbourhoodName`,
        `u`.`Email` AS `Email`
    FROM  `Add` AS `a`
    LEFT JOIN  `User` AS `u`  ON `u`.`ID` = `a`.`IDUser`
    LEFT JOIN  `Category` AS `ca1`  ON `ca1`.`ID` = `a`.`IDCategory`
    LEFT JOIN  `Category` AS `ca2`  ON `ca2`.`ID` = `ca1`.`IDParent`
    LEFT JOIN  `col_region` AS `r`  ON `r`.`Id` = `a`.`IDRegion`
    LEFT JOIN  `col_city` AS `ct`  ON `ct`.`Id` = `a`.`IDCity`
    LEFT JOIN  `col_neighbourhood` AS `n`  ON `n`.`Id` = `a`.`IDNeighbourhood`
    WHERE  (((((`a`.`DateTo` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
      AND  `a`.`IDStatus` = 1
      AND  `a`.`IDModeration` = 1)
      AND  (`a`.`IDStatus` <> 2))
      AND  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`a`.`DateAdded`) >= '1503430200'))
      AND  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`a`.`DateAdded`) <= '1505071799')
            )
      AND  (`a`.`IDCategory` = '43627'
              OR  `ca1`.`IDParent` = '43627'
              OR  `ca1`.`IDParent` IN (
                        SELECT  `ca3`.`ID` AS `ID`
                            FROM  `Category` AS `ca3`
                            WHERE  `ca3`.`IDParent` = '43627'))
           )
      AND  (`a`.`IDRegion` = '8')
    ORDER BY  `a`.`ID` DESC
    LIMIT  51
```

I'm not sure about indexes and how many indexes and on which field or fields is optimum for our case, as I mentioned before we have 14 million Ads records on our Website.

**update**

we are looking for optimizing table indexes according to our queries, we appreciate any clue or solution to achieve.

`Explain` of query :

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: a
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,IX_Add_DateFrom,IX_Add_IDUser,IX_Add_DateUpdated,IX_Add_DateUpToDated,IX_Add_DateTo,IX_Add_ON_IDUser_IDStatus_IDModeratiON_DateFrom_DateTo,IX_Add_DateAdded,IX_Add_Telephone,FK_Add_AddModeration,FK_Add_AddStatus,FK_Add_Category,FK_Add_col_city,FK_Add_col_neighbourhood,FK_Add_col_region,IDSource,IX_Add_Name,IX_Add_IP,IX_Add_UserType,IX_Add_IDUser_IDStatus,FullEditToken,IX_ExpiredAt
          key: FK_Add_AddStatus
      key_len: 5
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1480
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: u
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: trumpet.a.IDUser
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: ca1
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: trumpet.a.IDCategory
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: ca2
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: trumpet.ca1.IDParent
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: r
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: trumpet.a.IDRegion
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 6. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: ct
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: trumpet.a.IDCity
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 7. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: n
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: trumpet.a.IDNeighbourhood
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 8. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: aav
         type: ref
possible_keys: IX_AddAttributeValues_IDAdd
          key: IX_AddAttributeValues_IDAdd
      key_len: 4
          ref: trumpet.a.ID
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 9. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: catt
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: trumpet.aav.IDCategoryAttribute
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 10. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: gc
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,IX_GenericCollectiON_ON_IDType_INCLUDE_ID_Name_IDCategory_SortOr
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: trumpet.aav.Value
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 11. row ***************************
           id: 4
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: ai
         type: ref
possible_keys: IX_AddImage_IDAdd
          key: IX_AddImage_IDAdd
      key_len: 4
          ref: func
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 12. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: ac
         type: ref
possible_keys: IDAdd,IDModeration
          key: IDAdd
      key_len: 4
          ref: func
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
*************************** 13. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: ae
         type: ref
possible_keys: IDAdd
          key: IDAdd
      key_len: 4
          ref: func
         rows: 3
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
*************************** 14. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: adm
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: trumpet.ae.IDAdmin
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How big is the table -- in GB?

Comment: @RickJames 64 GB Ram, 14.44GB table size , and innodb_buffer_pool_size =134217728; innodb_buffer_pool_instances =1;

Comment: I responded to those sizes in my answer.  I await more query details.

Comment: @RickJames sure, thanks for your attention, I'm providing the most query are used in system and going to update question in 20 mins

Comment: @RickJames  buffer_pool_size  in live server is 20GB,  that number I've told you is in staging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this is not exact Query just a pseudo-code

Then we cannot necessarily give you the best indexes.  For example, it makes a big difference whether that `LONGTEXT` is part of the `SELECT *`.  This is because the value is *probably* an extra disk hit away.

> Left join to Location,Left join to User

I'm pretty sure the comma is a syntax error.  And without the `ON` clause, I suspect that the query is incomplete.

Please qualify all columns in the sample code by which table the are in.  For example, in query #1, it makes a *huge* difference whether `status` and `PostDate` are in the same table.

There is no `status` or `PostDate` in the one table you provided; please provide the other tables.

`status = 2` may be optimizable, but `status <> 2` is more complex.  Which is it?

I see

```
... AND  `a`.`IDStatus` = 1
... AND  (`a`.`IDStatus` <> 2)  -- Get rid of this?
```

Please address those issues.

Meanwhile, here's a few tentative answers

```
INDEX(status, PostDate) -- in that order (#1)

INDEX(IDModeration, IDStatus, DateTo)  -- DateTo last (in big query)

Find the 51 IDs first, _then_ `LEFT JOIN` to the other stuff.
```

Change this:

```
SELECT  1
                    FROM  `AddChanges` AS `ac`
                    WHERE  `ac`.`IDAdd` = `a`.`ID`
                      AND  `ac`.`IDModeration` = 4
                    ORDER BY  `ac`.`ID` DESC
                    LIMIT  1
```

to

```
EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM AddChanges
           WHERE IdAdd = a.ID
             AND IDModeration = 4 )
```

A messier issue that would help some:  Many of the datatypes in use are unnecessarily large.  For example, do you really need up to 2 billion Regions?  Shrinking the dataypes would shrink the dataset, which would make it more cacheable, hence less I/O, hence faster.

Single-column indexes on low-cardinality columns (IDModeration, IDStatus, UserType) tend to never be used.

Over-normalization can be costly (IDModeration, IDStatus).  That is, what is the advantage of having a table of statuses rather than an `ENUM` of the strings?  Also, `ENUM` is 1 byte versus 4 bytes for `INT`.

**Size**

With 64GB of RAM and 14GB of data, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to more than 14GB, but no more than 50GB; certainly not a tiny 128MB.  And set `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16` at that time.  Those changes will provide some amount of performance, perhaps a lot.  (It would be hard to be specific about how much improvement.)

**Specific queries**

For #1 detailed view.  Replace the current single-column index on `IDStatus` with

```
INDEX(IDStatus, IDModeration, DateTo, ID)
```

For detailed with state.  Replace single-column index on `IDRegion` with:

```
INDEX(IDRegion, IDStatus, IDModeration, DateTo, ID)
```

For detailed with category, the first index will work somewhat.  But also change

```
OR `ca1`.`IDParent` IN (
            SELECT  `ca3`.`ID` AS `ID`
                FROM  `Category` AS `ca3`
                WHERE  `ca3`.`IDParent` = '43627')
```

to

```
OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM `Category` AS `ca3`
                WHERE  ca1.ID = ID
                  AND  ca1.IDParent = 43627 )
```

and `Category` needs `INDEX(IDParent, ID)` unless it currently has `PRIMARY KEY(ID)`.

For detailed with date category state, do not "hide a column in a function".  In particular, change `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.DateAdded) >= '1503430200'` to

```
a.DateAdded >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1503430200)
```

Or (equivalently)

```
a.DateAdded >= '2017-08-22 12:30:00'
```

For summary mode, the above fixes will probably help.

Is that all that can be done?  I doubt it.  But, before digging deeper, I would like you to implement what you can of the above changes.  Then we can incrementally work on whatever seems best as the next step.

When providing `EXPLAIN`, please use `;`, not `\G`; I would rather struggle with "too wide" than "too high".

You are at the verge of hitting the StackOverflow limit of amount of text in a Question.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I'm going you update the question with the most queries are used.

Comment: I ask our DevOps team, they told me there are another services in the server needs Memory, like elastics, redis, etc . so they couldn't set the buffer_pool_size  to very high value.

Comment: I ask our DevOps team, they told me there are another services in the server needs Memory, like elastics, Redis, etc .but  buffer_pool_size  in live server is 20GB,  that number I've told you is in staging.

Comment: OK, 20G is reasonable for Production. 128M in Staging will lead to some queries running slower than Prod. Simply be aware of that.

Comment: Specific queries are now addressed.

Comment: Thanks, good notes are mentioned, I'm going to apply your suggestions.I'll inform you about the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
create index idx_add
on Ads(LocationID,status,PostDate,Id);
```

i think this indexes are enough if all other table are joined using primary key and you can also create create index on Location.state & Category.name

Comment: you suggest this because of my join order or where order conditions? do you think just one multi index is enough?

Comment: from the above query if you gonna use only left join i think this index will be optimal

Comment: your suggestion is based on order of left join, how about the order of where clauses?  I read some articles about  indexes based on where clauses

Answer (score 0):

These queries look optimized already. You can probably create temporary tables with indexes and join them, instead of making subqueries.
I doubt that playing with indexes will give you significant change in performance.

The only thing I would do here, if I was desperate for optimization, is to materialize queries. Looks like the parameters which change are region, category, date range and I doubt you really care about few minutes of lag when it comes to the date range.

So materialize your queries and fetch away with the max sql speed?

Comment: we have lots of users and temporary tables is not a good solution because each temp table created based on session and is valid for that user only.